# KML file seems to load in Openlayers without error but doesn't show vectors

Tags: kml, openlayers-2

I'm trying to load a KML file into an Openlayers map. It seems to successfully run but I am not seeing anything show up on the map.

Vectors should show up in an area of New Mexico if it's working correctly.

Here is my code (here is a link to the [KML file](http://ge.tt/api/1/files/9Th4rHW/0/blob?download) )

```js
var map;

var baseMaps = [];
var sensors = [];

//create map and center over location
var init = function () {
    // create map

    map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        theme: null,
        projection:new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG: 4326"),
        controls: [
            new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.TouchNavigation({
                dragPanOptions: {
                    enableKinetic: true
                }
            }),
            new OpenLayers.Control.Zoom()
        ],
        layers: [
            new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()
        ]
    });

    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-106.7653, 32.3197).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()),9);
};

//show kmlFile
var showSensor = function(sensorVO)
{
    if(sensorVO.selected == true)
    {
        var kmllayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: sensorVO.url,
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    extractStyles: true, 
                    extractAttributes: true,
                    maxDepth: 2
                })
            })
        });

        map.addLayer(kmllayer);
        var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(kmllayer);
        map.addControl(select);
        select.activate();  

        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-106.639261,32.649908).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject()),10);

        var obj = {"vo":sensorVO, "kmlLayer":kmllayer};
        sensors.push(obj);
    }

    else
    {

        for (var i = 0; i < sensors.length; i++) 
        {
            var vo = sensors[i].vo;
            if(vo.id == sensorVO.id)
            {
                map.removeLayer(vo.kmlLayer);
                sensors.splice(i, 1);
            }

        }

    }

}

init();

setTimeout(function(){
    var obj = {"id":1, "selected":true, "url":"kml-files/1858-Vegitation-Map.kml"};

    showSensor(obj);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: 105.9372, 35.6869 is incorrect Santa Fe is 35.6869, -105.9372

Comment: A bad practice: you add a new layer every second (e.g your timeout function) You'd better add the layer and only refresh it regularly >> http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Refresh-js.html

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't access your KML file to see if it's storing points of lines, but that would be a starting check.    KML can support the following geometries:  Point, LineString, LinearRing, Polygon and MultiGeometry. Since a KML file is ASCII rather than binary you can open  it in a text editor to make sure the coordinates are defined to the correct geometery.     The coordinates should be clearly specified. Does the KML say that they are  or  ?

Comment: I tried zipping the file and sharing. see if that helps http://ge.tt/2EdNlIW/v/0

Comment: I think you probably have your kml file uploaded correctly, I just can't retrieve due to a firewall from my end